# C# pointers, iterators and generics

Tags: c#, c++, generics, collections, iterator

I am greatly stumped

How can I use an iterator in C# like a C++ iterator? I cannot find a Begin() or End() accessor, I cannot even find out how to declare an iterator. I have read about the Ienumerator. My goal is to implement the Merge Function. Here is part of my Merge function written in C++. Mostly, I am looking for the C# equivalent of what is shown, except I will be using a Reference type rather than integers.

```
void merge(vector<int>::iterator left, vector<int>::iterator right, vector<int>::iterator      leftEnd, vector<int>::iterator rightEnd, vector<int>::iterator full)
{

    while(left != leftEnd && right!= rightEnd) //compare left and right until the end of the vector is reached
    {
        if(*right < *left)      //right < left so insert right to the output vector and advance the iterators
        {
            *full++ = *right++;
        }
        else                   //left < right so insert left to the output vector and advance the iterators
        {
            *full++ = *left++;
        }
    }

    while(left != leftEnd)    //copy any remaining elements into the output from left 
    {
        *full++ = *left++;
    }
}
```

Also, what collection(s) should I use? (currently I have been trying `List<T>` and `LinkedList<T>`).

Comment: Aren't you re-implementing the [Enumerable.Concat(Of TSource) Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx)?

Comment: @Serge no, this is the merge part of merge sort. Note `if(*right < *left)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
bool leftValid = left.MoveNext();
bool rightValid = right.MoveNext();

while (leftValid && rightValid)
{
    if (right.Current < left.Current)
    {
        full.Add(right.Current);
        rightValid = right.MoveNext();
    }
    else
    {
        full.Add(left.Current);
        leftValid = left.MoveNext();
    }
}

while (leftValid)
{
    full.Add(left.Current);
    leftValid = left.MoveNext();    
}

while (rightValid)
{
    full.Add(right.Current);
    rightValid = right.MoveNext();    
}
```

Here `full` would need to be some sort of `IList<T>` - .NET iterators don't let you make changes to the underlying collection.

You *shouldn't* try to write "bridging" code to let you use .NET iterators like C++ ones; it's much better to try to start thinking in terms of the .NET iterators when you're using .NET.

Note that it's quite rare to pass iterators around in .NET. It would be more natural to make your method to `IEnumerable<T>` parameters, and do something like:

```
using (IEnumerable<T> leftIterator = leftSequence.GetEnumerator())
{
    using (IEnumerable<T> rightIterator = rightSequence.GetEnumerator())
    {
        // Code as above, just using leftIterator and rightIterator
        // instead of left and right
    }
}
```

Comment: And note that `full` cannot be an iterator since .NET enumerators are read-only. You'll have to pass in something like `IList` instead.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: Indeed - will note that.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Sorry, yes, I'll clarify the bit about the immutability. I'm not sure what you mean about .NET not supporting creating copies of the iterators - you can create a method which takes two `IEnumerator<T>`s and it would work fine. It would make more sense to take `IEnumerable<T>`, mind you. I'll edit for that.

Comment: @JonSkeet Those iterators likely all point to different elements in the same container. Think of them as indices into a list, but working on collections that don't support fast indexing.

Comment: What are leftSequence.GetEnumerator() and rightSequence.GetEnumerator()

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: Calls to get the iterators; you'd make the method have parameters of `IEnumerable<T> leftSequence` and `IEnumerable<T> rightSequence`.

Answer (score 3):

.net containers don't support C++ style iterators. The only thing they have is a

- simple forward iterator called `IEnumerator<T>`
- which can't modify the collection
- isn't random access
- can't be copied (some collections have value type iterators which can be copied, but that's tricky business and rarely used)
- and on most collections also gets invalidated whenever you modify the collection

Pretty much the only thing they can do is being iterated over in a `foreach` statement.

---

You might want to look into the `IList<T>` interface which allows random access, but is only supported on collections which support fast indexing. On such a collection you could implement in-place merge sort by using indices.

```
void Merge<T>(IList<T> container,int left, int right, int leftEnd, int rightEnd, int full)
```

and then use `container[left]` instead of `*left`.

---

Unfortunate consequence of this is, that you can't implement an efficient in-place container agnostic sorting function like C++ has.

Comment: If we define iterator as a convenient container agnostic handle to a collection which keeps the current position and enables navigation, the only iterator type .NET supports is forward readonly iterator. Which is a pity. There are plenty of uses for bidirectional or random access iterators in many nontrivial algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want GetEnumerator(), MoveNext(), and Current.

Normally, you can just use foreach to iterate, but your case is special.

If fact, rather than using "full", organize this as an iterator block and merge two enumerables lazily.

```
IEnumerable<T> Merge<T>(IEnumerable<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right)
{
    ... yield return Min<T>(left.Current, right.Current); ..,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrays, which have a fixed size, or `List<T>`, which are also called ArrayLists in other languages. Their items can be accessed through an indexer (`list[i]`) and items can be appended with `list.Add(item);`. They grow automatically. `LinkedLists` cannot be accessed via an indexer and must be traversed.

You would declare the method like this

```cs
void merge(IEnumerator<int> left, IEnumerator<int> right, 
           List<int> full)
{
    // Jon Skeet's code goes here
}
```

You can get an enumerator like this

```
IEnumerable<int> intEnumerable = ...;
IEnumerator<int> intEnumerator = intEnumerable.GetEnumerator();
```

`IEnumerable<T>` is implemented by most generic collection types. Non generic collections usually implement `IEnumerable`.

(Edited in response to @CodeInChaos's comment).

Comment: There is no enumerable you could pass to `left`/`right`. Those are copies of partially iterated iterators.

Comment: I don't think that your edit addresses the problem. Those iterators likely all point to different elements in the same container. Think of them as indices into a list, but working on collections that don't support fast indexing.

Comment: An `IEnumerator<T>` (not `IEnumerable<T>`!) **is** a kind of index in a list. `left` and `right` can point to different locations in the same collection now. (I changed their type from `IEnumerable<int>` to `IEnumerator<int>`)

Comment: But (in general) you can't copy them. So you can't pass them to helper methods by value. And I think this copying ability is necessary in such an algorithm.

Comment: I did not realize that `List<T>` implements the enumerators as structs. I changed them to `ref` parameters now.

Comment: It is quite an unusual approach in C#. You would rather pass the collection plus indexes to the method as do QuickSort implementations.

Comment: Which has the significant problem that you can only apply it to collections with fast indexing. Also your `ref` params are nonsensically.

Comment: You suggested `ref` parameters. If the algorithm (which I do not know) requires copies, this will be achieved with by-value parameters, since the enumerators are structs. If, on the other hand, the caller needs the state of the enumerators after the call, then ref parameters will do it.

Comment: I said copies are required, and you can't copy iterators in *general*. In some specific cases it works, but you can't rely on that.